# Acessar ponteiro nulo não está gerando erro

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, ponteiro, null, gcc

Testando o código abaixo, notei um comportamento estranho. Ele está funcionando quando não deveria. O correto ao meu ver, era dar uma falha de segmentação e abortar, mas parece que o compilador está fazendo alguma mágica pra corrigir o código.

O que ocorre?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test{
public:
    void pa(){
    cout << "NULL????" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test * t = nullptr;
    t->pa();
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Está funcionando corretamente e gerando a saída:

```
NULL????
Hello world!
```

Os parâmetros para a compilação são os seguintes:

```
g++ -Weffc++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -std=c++11 -pg -m64 -g -fexceptions -g  -c main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/teste obj/Debug/main.o  -pg -m64
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Os métodos na verdade são funções normais que possuem um parâmetro escondido que é um referência para a instância que está usando (é o `this`). No caso não tem instância alguma. Não tem problema, o argumento a ser passado será um nulo. Mas a função pode ser chamada, não tem nada que impeça porque a função pertence àquela classe, o compilador sabe que ela existe. Algo assim:

```
void pa(test * this) {
```

Podemos entender que no fundo todos os métodos são estáticos, o que diferencia é apenas esse parâmetro escondido, por isso eles podem ser acessados em todas circunstâncias (na verdade métodos virtuais não pode por há um indireção e teria que acessar a *vtable* que, de alguma forma, não deixa de ser um membro de estado do objeto.

O problema aconteceria se dentro da função tentasse acessar algum membro de estado da instância, implícita ou explicitamente através do `this`. Aí precisaria acessar o dado em algum lugar da memória e ele não poderia ser nulo.

Funciona porque não impedimento técnico, mas conceitualmente está errado, é um "comportamento indefinido", não há garantias que sempre funcionará assim em todas plataformas, então o ideal é evitar esse tipo de chamada.

Isto já não funciona:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test {
    int x = 0;
public:
    void pa() {
        cout << x << "NULL????" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    test * t = nullptr;
    t->pa();
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}
```

Veja [**não** funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rBRW8h). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hqejaobe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/ErrorNull.cpp).

O método é "compilado" assim:

```
void pa(teste *this) {
    cout << this.x << "NULL????" << endl;
}
```

E por baixo dos panos a chamada seria:

```
pa(&t); //lembrando que t é nulo
```

Percebe porque o erro ocorre? Chamar a função não é um problema, acessar o parâmetro `this` é.

Comment: Obrigado, vou adicionar um membro na classe e tentar outra vez, já que o intuito aqui é forçar o erro

Eu ja tinha visto este comportamento ( this como paramentro implicito ) na linguagem Lua, legal saber que em C++ isso tambem se aplica, apesar de eu achar contra-intuitivo

Comment: Toma meu +1 aí. Rapaz, que resposta boa! P.S.: E engraçada também. rs Eu ri com o "Veja **não** funcionando no ideone.". :)

Comment: @LuizVieira nem todo mundo concordou com você, tomei negativo :(

Comment: Esse -1 merece um -1 (pela mesma provável lógica aplicada). :/